# IllegalStateException while using altbeacon library

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I am getting a crash in a few user's phones while using the altbeacon library. The stacktrace for the same is mentioned below. I have not been able to replicate the issue. Can someone help me with the resolution for this. I am using version 2.7 of the altbeacon library.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
BluetoothLeUtils.java line 136 in BluetoothLeUtils.checkAdapterStateOn()
BT Adapter is not turned ON

android.bluetooth.le
BluetoothLeUtils.java line 136 in BluetoothLeUtils.checkAdapterStateOn()
android.bluetooth.le
BluetoothLeScanner.java line 85 in BluetoothLeScanner$1.handleMessage()
android.os
Handler.java line 102 in Handler.dispatchMessage()
android.os
Looper.java line 168 in Looper.loop()
android.app
ActivityThread.java line 5885 in ActivityThread.main()
java.lang.reflect
Method.java line -2 in Method.invoke()
com.android.internal.os
ZygoteInit.java line 797 in ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()
com.android.internal.os
ZygoteInit.java line 687 in ZygoteInit.main()
```